# Import excel sheet into mysql database in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, excel, codeigniter

I am implementing an application in CodeIgniter for which there is some functionality requiring lots of data in an Excel sheet to be imported into a MySQL database via CodeIgniter. I have read about PHPExcel library but I don't quite understand it.

Comment: **[This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046246/import-excel-files-with-image-in-php-mysql?rq=1)** might help you.

Comment: Are you trying to do this a single time or is this an ongoing function that you want to construct?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to understand the documentation rather than `Reinventing the wheel`. The documentation isn't too hard . Here are few links which could help you get started.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md

Hope this helps.