# I want to import excel file in php/mysql with some images too. Does anyone has solution?

Tags: php, mysql, image, import-from-excel

I want to import excel file in php/mysql with some images too. Does anyone has solution? If Yes, Then plz reply with required software insatallation too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import excel files with image in php/mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046246/import-excel-files-with-image-in-php-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the library named as PHP Excel. Here is the [Link](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Here is the list of [Examples](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)

[Click here](http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=PHPExcel&DownloadId=94256) to view the Excel downloads with image

You will be giving the path like `$objDrawing->setPath('./images/phpexcel_logo.gif');`

And for more attributes

```
$objDrawing->setName('Paid');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Paid');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('B15');
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(110);
$objDrawing->setRotation(25);
```

You shall download the library and see the examples provided in it.

Comment: Plz will you send me steps to install PHP Excel on akkivaghasiya5@gmail.com